# Axis2 Web Service client TimeOut Configurations

Tags: web-services, configuration, timeout, apache-axis, broken-pipe

I have a web service which takes almost 5 minutes to run.
What I observed is my axis2 version 1.4 client doesnt wait for that much time and returns back. Thus my web service throws Broken Pipe.

I have set all below Options for timeout to 10 minutes.

```
HTTPConstants.REUSE_HTTP_CLIENT ==> Boolean.TRUE
HttpFactory.PARAMETER_THREAD_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME ==> new Integer(600000)
HttpFactory.PARAMETER_THREAD_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT ==> "MILLISECONDS"
HTTPConstants.HEADER_CONNECTION_KEEPALIVE ==> Boolean.TRUE
options.setTimeOutInMilliSeconds(new Integer(600000));
HTTPConstants.SO_TIMEOUT ==> new Integer(600000)
HTTPConstants.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT ==> new Integer(600000)
JMSConstants.JMS_WAIT_REPLY ==> new Integer(600000)
HttpFactory.PARAMETER_REQUEST_SOCKET_TIMEOUT ==> new Integer(600000)
```

I have also set similar configuration in axis2.xml

```
<parameter name="SO_TIMEOUT">600000</parameter>
<parameter name="CONNECTION_TIMEOUT">600000</parameter>
```

But None of these looks to be working. 
Can anybody suggest any missing configuration.